# Why am I getting "An error ocurred while starting the kernel" in Spyder while running Python?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have installed Anaconda (python 3.7) in my Windows 8.1 system. However, while running my Python code from the Spyder console, I am getting the following error:

`An error occurred while starting the kernel`

I have checked the PATH environment variable and everything is correct.

Here is the detailed error received in the console while trying to execute the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
>
> kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
>
> self.write_connection_file()
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
> line 547, in write_connection_file
>
> kernel_name=self.kernel_name
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
> line 212, in write_connection_file
>
> with secure_write(fname) as f:
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in **enter**
>
> return next(self.gen)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
>
> with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\bharat\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernelbcba4480cd.json'

Answer (score 7):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To solve this problem please open the Anaconda Prompt and run there

```
conda update anaconda
conda install jupyter_client=5.3.4
```

Comment: Thanks a million, been stuck with this for hours. Why is it not solved yet if it is a known error though? I got it after a clean anaconda installation on windows

Comment: This didn't work in my case.  When I first installed Anaconda Spyder worked when running from Base, but now I get this error when running from an environment.

Answer (score -1):

Simply running Spyder as Administrator solved the same issue for me.

Comment: This is not a good answer because you're exposed to wipe out your file system by running `os.remove`, for instance.